# Proving that the root exists given a particular condition holds true.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Let $p (x)=a_0+a_1x^2+a_2x^3+...+a_nx^{n+1}$  and $\sum _i \frac {a_i}{i+1}=0$ then prove that there is atleast a $x_0$ st $p (x_0)=0$  . Differentiating we have  $p '(x)=0$ for $x=0$ . As $p (x )$ being a continuous and differentiable we have extremum at $x=0$ which is $a_0$ . Let $a_0$ be a maxima. Now if $a_0 <0$ then the function is always negative and hence we cannot have a root . If $a_0=0$ then $0$ is a root. If $a_0>0$ then function has to have atleast $2$ roots. Same can be done if we take $a_0$ as minima. Is this a correct proof. If not why? And whats the use of second condition ie $\sum_i \frac {a_i}{i+1}=0$ ?

Comment: It look's strange... There is a well-known problem: let $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^{n}$ and $\sum \frac{a_i}{i+1}=0$, then $p(x)$ has a root. May be your conditions are not correct?

Comment: Yes i know of it but i am confused with my given problem.

Comment: Your proof is not correct, because you don't fill the difference between "local maxima" and "global maxima": $x=0$ can be a local maxima with $p(0)<0$. for example $p(x)=x^4-x^2-1$. (Sorry for my english...)